# How to import firebase accounts with the same password?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication to manage my users accounts.

Now, I need to change the uid of the users, then I'm trying to delete the user and import it again with the same password using python.

I'm trying to follow the documentation. But I might be missing something.

So, in the Firebase authentication page, I'm going to menu (in the right upper corner) and getting the `base64_signer_key` and `base64_salt_separator` values.

And trying to use the code below to delete the user, import the user and update the other fields:

```py
    for user in auth.list_users().iterate_all():
        if user.email == 'myname@yahoo.com':

            newId = CPF(cpf()).rawValue
            oldId = user.uid

            print('User: {}'.format(user._data))

            # Delete the user
            auth.delete_user(oldId)

            # Recreate the user
            users = [
                auth.ImportUserRecord(
                    uid=newId,
                    email=user.email,
                    password_hash=user.password_hash.encode('utf-8'),
                    password_salt=None
                ),
            ]

            hash_alg = auth.UserImportHash.scrypt(
                key=base64.b64decode(base64_signer_key),
                salt_separator=base64.b64decode(base64_salt_separator),
                rounds=8,
                memory_cost=14
            )       
            try:
                result = auth.import_users(users, hash_alg=hash_alg)
                print('Successfully imported {0} users. Failed to import {1} users.'.format(
                    result.success_count, result.failure_count))
                for err in result.errors:
                    print('Failed to import {0} due to {1}'.format(users[err.index].uid, err.reason))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            # Update user
            auth.update_user(
                newId,
                phone_number=user.phone_number,
                email_verified=user.email_verified,
                display_name=user.display_name,
                disabled=user.disabled
            )
```

I'm following this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_with_firebase_scrypt_hashed_passwords

I'm able to delete and recreate the user, but when I try to login with the same user/password I'm getting `FirebaseInvalidPasswordError`.

What should I do recreate the user with same password and be able to authenticate in the standard way ?

Comment: I realized a similar function (in NodeJS) to export and re-import users across different Firebase projects. In my case, during the export phase, I also obtain the user "salt", and use it as and argument during the import. I see in [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users) they also use a salt, while you have "None". Could this explain your issue?

Comment: Hi @MattiaGalati in my case there is also an `user.password_salt`, but is coming None from the Firebase API, that is why a put None.

Comment: Does the password_hash of the users you get from listing is `UkVEQUNURUQ=` ?

Answer (score 2):

After many tests, maybe I've managed to find a working way to solve the problem.

First of all, if you have created a new service account private key, go to GCP console here [https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?authuser=0&project=[your_firebase-proect-id]](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?authuser=0&project=%5Byour_firebase-proect-id%5D) and make sure your service account have the "Firebase Authentication" admin rights

(note the service account)
[image: Note the service account]

(check permission)
[image]

This was my first problem since without that permission, the firebase admin SDK always returns an empty `password_salt` and the string "*UkVEQUNURUQ=*" for the `password_hash` (which translates to "REDACTED").

Once I got the correct password hash and salt for user, your code should looks like this

```py
    # Recreate the user
    users = [
        auth.ImportUserRecord(
            uid=newId,
            email=user.email,
            password_hash=base64.urlsafe_b64decode(user.password_hash),
            password_salt=base64.urlsafe_b64decode(user.password_salt)
        ),
    ]
```

Note the `base64.urlsafe_b64decode` part? I've tried to manually export my probject users with the firebase cli though

```
firebase auth:export --project [project-id] users.csv
```

and noticed a big difference: **Python** password hash was
`utfZLdz4phgAnRIKRUOxxFTKmbUEenbV1CbkQC0o4iorXpx-BJsdwofjAQkb1mUAgs_sO49cBv_lT8QuCztRzA==` while **CSV** password hash was `utfZLdz4phgAnRIKRUOxxFTKmbUEenbV1CbkQC0o4iorXpx+BJsdwofjAQkb1mUAgs/sO49cBv/lT8QuCztRzA==` (in python slashes are undercores)

Don't know if my approach would cover all cases, but exporting auth from the cli and comparing their hashes with the python ones could lead you to solve further cases.

Comment: Setting the permission, I'm now getting the salt, but still not creating the user with a valid password :(

Comment: @KleysonRios have you checked the ouput of the CSV and compared the password hashes you obtain from CSV against the ones in Python? I would suggest to export the CSV, and hardcode the CSV hash into python code to check if this first approach result in a success.